# In js How to replace confirm()

Tags: javascript

I'm using `confirm()` in this code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
    const credForms = document.querySelectorAll('form.cred-user-form');
    for (const form of credForms) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        const result = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet utilisateur ?");

        if (!result) {
          event.preventDefault();
          location.reload();
        } 

      });
    }
  });
```

How to replace it by nice popup which were as blocking as `confirm()`?

I'm looking for a js function which displays a popup with yes and no buttons.

Answer (score -1):

you can try using sweet alert library

```
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
    const credForms = document.querySelectorAll('form.cred-user-form');
    for (const form of credForms) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet utilisateur?',
          showDenyButton: true,
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
          denyButtonText: `No`,
        }).then((result) => {
          /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            Swal.fire('User Deleted!', '', 'success')
          } else if (result.isDenied) {
            Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
            event.preventDefault();
            location.reload();
          }
        })
      });
    }
  });
```